# How find XPATH with random number value in attribute?

Tags: regex, xml, xpath

I have div blocks on website like this: `<div id="banner-XXX-1"></div>`

So I need to query this banner, where XXX is any digit number.

How to do that? Currently I use this way:
`//div[contains(@id,'banner-') and contains(@id,'-1')]`

But this way is not good if XXX starts with `1`. So, is there any way to do like this: `//div[contains(@id,'banner-' + <any_decimal> + '-1')]`?

---

It seems `match` operator on popular Chrome plugin XPath Helper does not work, so I use v1.0
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl?hl=en

Comment: Please always say which XPath version you are using. Solutions using XPath 2.0+ are often much easier, but many people are still using version 1.0.

Comment: I don't know what version I have. But it seems `match` operator does not work, my software says invalid expression

Comment: Usually if people don't know which version they are using, it is version 1.0, because if it's been upgraded to a later version, the vendors will be very keen to tell you about this, while 1.0 vendors like to keep quiet that they're implementing such an ancient version of the specification.

Comment: @MichaelKay, had XPath required a version-reporting function, it could have allowed a return value of `"too-embarrassed-to-say"` to accommodate such concerns.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XPath 1.0

This XPath 1.0 expression,

```
//div[    starts-with(@id,'banner-') 
      and translate(substring(@id, 8, 3), '0123456789', '') = ''
      and substring(@id, 11) = '-1']
```

selects all `div` elements whose `id` attribute value

- starts with `banner-`,
- followed by 3 digits, which a `translate()` trick mapped to nothing,
- followed by `-1`,

as requested.

### XPath 2.0

This XPath 2.0 expression,

```
//div[matches(@id,'^banner-\d{3}-1$')]
```

selects all `div` elements whose `id` attribute value matches the shown regex and

- starts (`^`) with `banner-`,
- followed by 3 digits, (`\d{3}`),
- and ends (`$`) with `-1`,

as requested.